# Having trouble with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Recently while working on a website, I was having an issue with innerHTML as a part of a javascript function. The code can be found here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Page That Wouldn't Work</title>
</head>
<body>


Access Code: <input type="text" size="10" id="codeEntered"> <button type="button" onclick="codeEffect();">Submit</button>

<div id="wrongCode">This is the div.</div>

<script>
var codeEffect = function()
{
if (codeEntered.value == "761825")
        window.location.href = "TheSiteForThePeopleWithTheCode.com";
else
        //alert("This part of the code is running.")
        document.getElementByID('wrongCode').innerHTML = "You entered the code incorrectly.";
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The intended functionality is that if the correct access code is entered, the user will be directed to a different page, but if the code is entered incorrectly, then they will get a message in a  below the text field saying that they had entered the code incorrectly.

Currently, when the code is entered incorrectly and the button is pressed, nothing happens.

I had searched around the internet to figure out what could be going wrong and thought I had figured out that my div wasn't yet defined when I was calling the function, however I then changed that and it didn't have any effect.

What is the issue? I appreciate any insights greatly. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I know that part of the function is being executed if the code is entered incorrectly because I tested it with an alert('').

Comment: Synatax error : it is getElementById() not getElementByID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Always* check your error console. `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`.

Also, be careful when omitting curly braces. Only the first line will be treated as part of the block.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean about the curly braces? I have one to open the function and one to close it -- where was one omitted? My apologies if I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: @MattLevine: The `if` and the `else` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's a typo, but the method name is `getElementById` (lower case d). You should see an error in the console.